# when grouping by date, wrong dates are shown

Tags: ios, swift

I have a struct like so:

```
struct myStruct {
    let date: Date
    let details: [Detail]
}
```

I have an array of `myStruct`

Basically I would like to group them by the date, but the problem I'm having with the way im doing it is that it isnt accurate when grouping the dates.

for example I have a date from the 23rd of June. But in its becoming the 22nd.

Could it be when decoding its incorrect?

Here's how I decode it:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)
```

Then to group it:

```
let cal = Calendar.current
let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: results, by: { cal.startOfDay(for: $0.date) })

let sortedKeys = grouped.keys.sorted { $1 < $0 }
let data = sortedKeys.map { key in
return DateSection(date: key, details: grouped[key]!)
}
```

backend stored date : `2018-06-23T03:57:47.349Z UTC`

after decoding,  sorting and grouping date becomes `June 22, 2018`

Comment: What evidence do you have of this problem?

Comment: Are you getting your dates from an API or are you generating them on the device?

Comment: "for example I have a date from the 23rd of June. But in its becoming the 22nd.". Are you sure it failed? How so? What are the results? What are the dates? Did you get an issue after grouping, or directly in the decoding? I'd go with a TimeZone issue.

Comment: @rmaddy the dates just don't match up with my backend.

Comment: But why don't you think they match? Show clear specific details showing actual data and output.

Comment: @rmaddy i added what is the actual data is and then the output, I have a feeling its happening during decoding or the dictionary grouping part?

Comment: Your results are perfectly valid depending on where you live. The stored date is nearly 4am on the 23rd UTC time. Depending on where you live that could be roughly 4pm on the 22nd to 4pm on the 23rd local time.

Comment: i see, so nothings incorrect? Whats the time conversion if I may ask?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in one of the comments, the date returned might be in UTC and you might be in a UTC-x zone. If we put x=3 And the time in UTC is 23 June 2:00:00 am, then in UTC-3 it becomes 22 June 11:00:00 pm